# For the covariance formula, how are subtraction and multiplication defined for real-valued random variables.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, real-numbers, covariance

Covariance is defined as 
$$E\left[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])\right]$$
If $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables, how do we do multiplication and scalar subtraction on them?

Comment: Do you mean, what is the covariance of their sum/difference and product? Because random variables are just measurable functions, so these operations are defined pointwise for them.

Comment: @Calvin, yeah, real-valued random variables are basically just PDFs, right? What is pointwise? I mean, how do you solve $X - E[X]$ and $XY$, for example. I guess you do some calculus?

Comment: "real-valued random variables are basically just PDFs, right?" Well, no, not at all. Random variables are *functions*... hence, provided they are defined on the same probability space, one can add them and multiply them and substract them and so on.

Comment: @Did ok, so a random variable is more like a cumulative distribution function (which is derived from a PDF)? How do you multiply two functions?

Comment: No, a random variable is not a CDF either, **a random variable is a function**. If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ and $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ then $XY:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)Y(\omega)$.

Comment: @Did Ok, I get that its a function, which wouldn't exclude it from being a CDF, but what kind of function is it? I don't understand this notation ω↦X(ω)Y(ω). What is ω and ↦ ?

Comment: No, random variables are not their CDF. The notation means that the function $Z=XY$ is defined on $\Omega$ by $Z(\omega)=X(\omega)Y(\omega)$ for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: @Did Looking at the OP's background, I have decided to remove my comment.

Comment: Ok, so a real-valued random variable maps all possible 'outcomes' onto a real value. There is no arithmetic mapping between the two, because the set of all possible outcomes is just like an un-ordered  list of things that can happen? And multiple outcomes can map to the same value? But the concept of outcomes is at least useful to us here, because it allows us to understand $X$ and $Y$ as measurements of the same outcome, but differing in kind?

Comment: One might say things like that, yes.

Comment: Ok. But then it seems that if we actually want to compute the covariance, then we are back to talking about PDFs.

Comment: Not all random variables have a PDF but if the PDFs exist then yes they can be useful to compute covariances. Is this your question? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function, $g:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, and continuously distributed real valued random variables $X,Y$, with joint probability distribution function $f_{X,Y}$, then:

$$\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) = \iint_{\Bbb R^2} g(x,y)\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname dx$$

Hence:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E\Big(\big(X-\mathsf E(X)\big)\big(Y-\mathsf E(Y)\big)\Big) & = \iint_{\Bbb R^2} \big(x-\mathsf E(X)\big)\big(y-\mathsf E(Y)\big)\, f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\\[2ex] = \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y) & = \iint_{\Bbb R^2} xy \, f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x-\int_\Bbb R x\,f_X(x)\operatorname d x\int_\Bbb R y\,f_Y(y)\operatorname d y\end{align}$$